# Codeigniter session array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting only this from the codeigniter default session array

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1450553587 )
```

Need session_id,ip etc

I am using codeigniter 3

Comment: can you show how you have set session??

Comment: I load session library in autoload and just print the default array   print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit();

Comment: you need to add some code to your session.php file , please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter 3.0.x does not put (all) session metadata in the $_SESSION array.
Here is how to access the items not found there.

```
    echo "Session ID:".session_id()."<br>";
    echo "Remote Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."<br>";
    echo "User Agent: ".$this->input->user_agent()."<br>";
```

And to get the last session regenerate

```
    echo "Last Regenerate: ".($_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you would add this peace of code to your Session.php in your system folder.

```
$_SESSION['ip_address'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

add this peace of code to your

Codeigniter_Project_path\system\libraries\Session in Session.php

after:

```
session_start();
```

this will be the result:

> array(2) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1450542332) ["ip_address"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" }

**UPDATE**

[Check this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata)

```
    session_id: session_id()
    ip_address: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    user_agent: $this->input->user_agent() (unused by sessions)
    last_activity: Depends on the storage, no straightforward way. Sorry!
```

these properties must be added to the session.php with generating new session.